# what does @ stand for in a Ruby function name

Tags: ruby

What does @ stand for in the following Ruby code:

```
module TestRocket
  extend Module.new { attr_accessor :out }

  def _test(a, b); send((call rescue()) ? a : b); end

  def +@; _show _test :_pass, :_fail end
  def -@; _show _test :_fail, :_pass end
  def ~@; _show _pend;               end
  def !@; _show _desc;               end

  def _show(r); (TestRocket.out || $>) << r; r end
  def _pass; "     OK\n"; end
  def _fail; "   FAIL @ #{source_location * ':'}\n"; end
  def _pend; "PENDING '#{call}' @ #{source_location * ':'}\n"; end
  def _desc; "   FIRE '#{call}'!\n"; end
end

Proc.send :include, TestRocket
```

Then this is used as:

```
+-> { Die.new(2) }
--> { raise }
+-> { 2 + 2 == 4 }
```

How does @ turn into '->' in the function name?

Comment: good question. I've never seen this. But if you try and run `+-> { 2+2==4 }` without it you get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for #<Proc:0x0000010>`. So I guess this is a magic method from ruby 1.9

Comment: TestRocket's repository is https://github.com/peterc/testrocket

Comment: http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method names for the four unary operators `+`, `-`, `~`, and `!` are `+@`, `-@`, `~@`, and `!@`. So the funny looking method definitions:

```
def +@; _show _test :_pass, :_fail end
def -@; _show _test :_fail, :_pass end
def ~@; _show _pend;               end
def !@; _show _desc;               end
```

just define overloads for those four unary operators. Then TestRocket is patched into the Proc class using `Proc.send :include, TestRocket`.

This:

```
-> { Die.new(2) }
```

is simply a lambda definition and another way of writing `lambda { Die.new(2) }`. Then, with TestRocket patched into Proc we can say this:

```
+-> { Die.new(2) }
# + lambda { Die.new(2) }
```

and it will run this method:

```
def +@; _show _test :_pass, :_fail end
```

as an instance method on that lambda.

Looks like a bit of an abuse of the unary operator overloading to "invent" something that looks like new `-->`, `~->`, ... operators.