# What does -@ operator do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've found the -@ operator redefinition in Rails/ActiveSupport:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L33

Can you tell me what does it mean?

Comment: It's just a variable name I guess...

Comment: Semi-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816444/what-does-stand-for-in-a-ruby-function-name

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, it contains more information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-@` and `+@` are simply the method names for unary `-` and `+`.  If you want to redefine them, invoke them as methods, etc., that's how you need to refer to them to distinguish them from binary `-` and `+`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it defines what happens when the object is negated, for example:

```
x = -y
```

The y object needs to have a -@ operator defined.

Answer (score 0):

It simply returns a negated duration object, where the value is negated and all the values of parts are also negated.