# How to define a method to_proc in Array so I can use it in a particular situations

Tags: ruby, overriding, proc

Lets say that I have the class:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :brand, :color
  def initialize(br, col)
    @brand = br
    @color = col 
  end
end

first_car = Car.new 'Mercedes', 'Yellow'
second_car = Car.new 'Jaguar', 'Orange'
third_car = Car.new 'Bentley', 'Pink'

array_of_cars = [first_car, second_car]
```

So, the idea is to define a method `to_proc` in the class Array so this can happen:

```
array_of_cars.map(&[:brand, :color]) #=> [['Mercedes', 'Yellow'], ['Jaguar', 'Orange'], ['Bentley', 'Pink']]
```

or how could I somehow do something like this:

```
[:brand, :color].to_proc.call(first_car) #=> ['Mercedes', 'Yellow']
```

Comment: Would you want to hard code `&[:brand, :color]` in your `to_proc` implementation?

Comment: Well, it would be nice if I could do it dynamically no matter what is the object but if you have an idea I would be happy to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `Symbol#to_proc` is, more or less, a `e.send(self)` call and you just want to `send` an array full of symbols to each element so just say exactly that with something like this:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    proc { |e| self.map { |m| e.send(m) } }
  end
end
```

I'd probably not patch Array for this, I'd just use a local lambda if I wanted something easier to read:

```
brand_and_color = lambda { |e| [:brand, :color].map { |s| e.send(s) } }
array_of_cars.map(&brand_and_color)
```

Comment: I am quite new in ruby and there are many things I am not familiar with. In your example if I had [first_car, second_car].map(&[:brand, :color]) on each iteration what is 'e', 'self' and 'm'. I am getting a little confused.

Comment: `self` will be the array itself (i.e. `[:brand, :color]`), `e` will be the element of `array_of_cars` that is being send to the proc, and `m`  will be the element of `self` (i.e. the method to be called). The [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) documentation might be worth reading.

Comment: if I'm not mistaking calling this patched `to_proc` would return a proc object not an array ?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh: Yes, if `to_proc` doesn't return a proc then `&array` will just be a fancy way of raising a TypeError.

Comment: @muistooshort hahaha, lol Understood. Yeah, I find it weird why the method has to be specifically called `to_proc` ?

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. What if I didn't have the .map but something else like .reduce or .zip ?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh: I think it should be `def &@` to match the other unary operator methods. I'm not sure if unary `&` really is an operator though, it could just be a hack that calls `to_proc`...

Comment: @user2128702: I don't understand what you mean. You can't `array_of_cars.zip(a, &:brand)` so...

Comment: Yeah, however :) Never mind. I guess that I could Apply that in other cases. I'll try to experiment a little bit now. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @muistooshort `&` in Ruby is a bitwise operator.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh: The *binary* `&` is *sometimes* a bitwise operator (`a & b` is a set-wise intersection with Arrays and Sets for example). Consider the difference between `def -(x)` and `def -@`, the first is a binary `a - b` operator whereas the second is a unary `-a` operator. You'll find similar things with `+` and `~` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7816555/479863).

Comment: @muistooshort that was a very detailed explanation. I enjoyed reading through it and didn't knew that you could do method overloading with `@` But, my stance was that `&` in Ruby is a pure bitwise operator when no method overloading is in play.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh: Does the "no method overloading is in play" concept even apply in Ruby? All I'm saying is that `-a` is just `a.send('-@')` so `&a` really should be `a.send('&@')` rather than `a.send('to_proc')` for consistency. The `@` in the unary operator method names is, AFAIK, just a kludge to differentiate them from the binary operator methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array

  def to_proc(arr)
    self.map do |elem|
       arr.map { |attr| elem.send(attr) }
    end
  end

end
```

Like `mu is too short` mentioned, I wouldn't patch `Array` like this.

But, this will get the work done for you.

Invoke it as such:

```
array_of_cars.to_proc([:brand, :color])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a normal method?

```
module ConvertInstanceToHash

  def to_proc(obj, keys)
    hash = {}
    obj.instance_variables.each {|var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = obj.instance_variable_get(var)}
    hash = hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
    hash.values_at(*keys).compact
  end

end

irb(main):009:0> first_car = Car.new 'Mercedes', 'Yellow'
=> #<Car:0x000000045fb870 @brand="Mercedes", @color="Yellow">
irb(main):010:0> to_proc(first_car, [:brand, :color])
=> ["Mercedes", "Yellow"]
```